# Eclipse - Console view is on a missing screen

Tags: eclipse

I had 2 screens. I put the console view (along with other views) on the secondary screens. Now I removed the other screen while eclipse was running. Now I can't access those views that were on the secondary view. when I try to open them from the window menu, I can't see them. Tried to press escape while they were on focus, but now when I open them I see a blank detached window with nothing in it...

Running windows, on dell laptop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried to reset your perspective?